# Can not PXE Boot through SCCM

Tags: windows-server-2012, pxe-boot, sccm-2012-r2

I have created a fresh installation of SCCM 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2012. I created a task sequence for an OS deployment on a single machine. When I go to PXE boot the machine I get the following error:

```
Architecture: 64

The details below show the information relating to the PXE boot request for this computer. Please provide these
details to your windows deployment services Administrator so that this request can be approved.

Pending Request ID:6

Message From Administrator:
   Configuration Manager is looking for policy.

Contacting Server: 10.3.10.93.

PXE Boot aborted. Booting to next device...
```

The last entry in `SMSPXE.log` is from yesterday:

```
================= PXE Provider shutdown. =====================
```

The most recent errors in the log are:

```
InstallBootFilesForImage failed. 0x80004005

Warning: Failed to copy the needed boot binaries from the boot image
D:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\POB00005\boot.POB00005.wim. 
The operation completed successfully. (Error: 00000000; Source: Windows)
Failed adding image D:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\POB00005\boot.POB00005.wim. Will Retry.. 
Unspecified error (Error: 80004005; Source: Windows)
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a 64bit pxe boot image and associated sequence?

Comment: I just took a look at the deployment and under the references, the boot image was there but I noticed there were 0 targets for that image. I distributed the boot image to my distribution points and now it shows 6, I will try again and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried, and getting the same error.

Comment: Is a PXE boot image different than the two (x64 and x86) boo images that are automatically added into SCCM?